# How to access props from Parent Component inside the Child Class Component ? (specifically for componentDidMount)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, components

I want to use the {prop.idno} from parent to child in componentDidMount() fetch call URL . How do I make use of idno in the URL to call different posts pages.

Is there a way to write it like this?

```
const response = await fetch(
       `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId= ${this.prop.idno}`
      );
```

Parent Component :

```
return (
<>
  <TogglePosts idno = {user.id}/>
</>
)
```

Child Component:

```
export class TogglePosts extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      on: false,
      data: [],
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      on: !this.state.on,
    });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("comp did mount");
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);

      this.setState({ data: data, loaded: true });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try editing your response similar to this.

```
    const response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId= ${this.props.idno}`
      );
```

Note that I've used `(tilde) instead of "(double quotes)
Also use `props` instead of `prop`

Comment: I realized that, but it still doesn't work. Seems like {this.props.idno} is just not available in componentDidMount. It shows it's undefined on console.log

Answer (score 0):

Can you try accessing it using props.idno in the TogglePosts Component?
In the fetch statement you can do something like fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${props.idno}`);

Comment: I realized that, but it still doesn't work. Seems like {this.props.idno} is just not available in componentDidMount. It shows it's undefined on console.log

Comment: I would suggest in order to debug, try logging the idno in the calling component (which calls TogglePosts) and also try logging idno in the constructor of the TogglePosts component. May be we can narrow down the root cause of error by doing this.

Comment: It shows undefined in render() and in componentDidMount() at the first run. Then it displays in render() but not in componentDidMount().

Comment: What do you mean by first run? Are you updating your component somehow?

Comment: i meant the react lifecycle. Like first it runs the render() method and then the componentDidMount()

Comment: I understand the react lifecycle part. "It shows undefined in render() and in componentDidMount() at the first run" What does "first run" mean here?
Sorry its a bit confusing may be if you could post more portions of your code, might be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId= ${this.props.idno}`
      );
```

Template literal(``) is the ability to include expressions and variables within a string.

Comment: I realized that, but it still doesn't work. Seems like {this.props.idno} is just not available in componentDidMount. It shows it's undefined on console.log